# How to use BestOf2NearestMatcher

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, homography

I am trying to find the pairwise matches between descriptors of two images so that Ican estimate homography between them. There are other methods like `BFMatcher` and `FlannBasedMatcher` but I want to use `BestOf2NearestMatcher`. I have used following syntax:

```
vector<MatchesInfo> pairwise_matches;
detail::BestOf2NearestMatcher matcher(false,0.3,10,10);
matcher(features,pairwise_matches);
matcher.collectGarbage();
```

I am facing a problem as the `pairwise_matches` contains no matches and no inliers. I suspect there is some problem in `matcher`. If I implement a `BFMatcher` or a `FlannBasedMatcher` then I get 46 matches. Has anybody used this method?

More information on `BestOf2NearestMatcher` can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/matching.html?highlight=bestof2near#detail%3a%3aBestOf2NearestMatcher%3apublicdetail%3a%3aFeaturesMatcher).

Answer (score 1):

BestOf2NearestMatcher is implementation of the Lowe`s 2nd nearest neighbor ratio criterion described in SIFT paper, where he recommend to use ratio = 0.8. The same holds for the SURFs. Sometimes even 0.85. Value in 0.3 is too strictive.

Comment: OpenCV has a demo on image stitching, where 0.65 is used in the case of a SIFT descriptor and 0.3 is used for the ORB descriptor.

Comment: OpenCV has a demo on homography estimation with idiotic strategy of selecting "good matches" which contradicts Lowe`s paper. So "OpenCV has a demo" is not argument :)
But 0.65 can be threshold for squared ratio: 0.8^2 = 0.64.

Comment: All I am saying is that 0.3 is apparently not too restrictive for ORB descriptors.